# Selected string value of select not posting in asp.net MVC core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I have a string property in my model defined as

```
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "Day Of Week")]
 public string DayOfWeek { get; }
```

Need to bind a dropdown for this so initiated ViewData as

```
var dayoftheweeks = new List<dynamic>() {
                          new  { DayOfWeek= "Monday"},
                          new { DayOfWeek="Tuesday"},
                          new { DayOfWeek="Wednesday"},
                          new { DayOfWeek="Thursday"},
                          new { DayOfWeek="Friday"},
                          new { DayOfWeek="Saturday"},
                          new { DayOfWeek="Sunday"}
                        };

        ViewData["DayOfWeek"] = new SelectList(dayoftheweeks, "DayOfWeek", "DayOfWeek", dayoftheweek);
```

and on the view it is implemented as

```
<select asp-for="DayOfWeek" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.DayOfWeek"></select>
```

It binds the dropdown correctly but when I post the form `DayOfWeek` property `comes as a null`.

Confirmed that this selects select list `options` as a `Value` property rendered to it too.
This is how it renders on page

```
<option value="Monday">Monday</option>
```

However I have used dropdown in another page where selected value is integer field. There it is posting selected value. I wonder if this is only with string selected Value.

Can you please guide if I am missing anything?

**Updated**
It started working. Initially when there was a problem I had defined a property as

```
 [Required]
 [MaxLength(150)]
 [Display(Name = "Day Of Week")]
 // Comment statement
 public string DayOfWeek { get; set; }
```

To make it work, I just moved the comment part above of all anotations as

```
// Comment statement
 [Required]
 [MaxLength(150)]
 [Display(Name = "Day Of Week")]
 public string DayOfWeek { get; set; }
```

I still dont know the reason why comments placement make an impact.

Comment: I have created a test demo on my side, I have moved the comment part after of all anotations and it still work well.  I guess this may be related with the validation you have used. Please post the details view with js and controller codes for us to test.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to define an enum for day of week such as this :

```
public enum DayOfWeek : byte
    {
        Monday = 0,
        Tuesday = 1,
        Wednesday = 2,
        Thursday = 3,
        Friday = 4,
        Saturday = 5,
        Sunday = 6
    }
```

and then in view use this select same as shown below :

```
<select asp-for="DayOfWeek" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<DayOfWeek>()" class="form-control"></select>
```